# E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while updating php

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt

I tried to update php to php5 and getting below errors.

```
root@Ansible-VirtualBox:~# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libbsd0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libedit2 libgd3 libvpx1
  php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-json
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom libgd-tools
  php-pear php5-user-cache
Recommended packages:
  php5-readline
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-mpm-prefork apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data libgd3 libvpx1 php5-json
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-utils libedit2 php5-cli php5-common php5-gd
6 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 3 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,489 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,659 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 177484 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2-bin (from .../apache2-bin_2.4.17-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.17-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.17-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am getting below error when I tried removing the previously installed versions and packages.

```
root@Ansible-VirtualBox:~# apt-get remove apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.30+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@Ansible-VirtualBox:~# apt-get remove apache2.2-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-mpm-prefork : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.30+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@Ansible-VirtualBox:~# apt-get remove apache2-
apache2-mpm-prefork  apache2-utils        
root@Ansible-VirtualBox:~# apt-get remove apache2
apache2              apache2.2-bin        apache2.2-common     apache2-mpm-prefork  apache2-utils
root@Ansible-VirtualBox:~# apt-get remove apache2.2-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 apache2-mpm-prefork : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.30+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Do not post a screenshot of text. It's difficult to read, impossible to read if you're blind, and impossible to search. Copy-paste the text.

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause.

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.17-2+deb.sury.org-precise+1_i386.deb (--unpack)
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
```

You have obviously *three* (!!) versions of `apache` installed at the same time (or "only" two, and you're *attempting* to add a third one): v2.2.22, v2.4.17 and v2.8.
This is not recommended at all and even **prone to errors respectively server malfunction**!

You should either stick strictly to **one** of the three versions of `apache` you have and *uninstall* all remaining apache versions (i. e. the 2.2.22 one and the 2.4.17 from Ubuntu Precise Pangolin):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove <name of previous package(s)>
```

(try to enter `apa` and then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to select the correct package name)

Your system seems pretty messed up with this weird jumble of `apache` versions.